# How change keyframes position on element

Tags: javascript, css

```
<div id="slider">
    <figure>
        <img src="http://www.codelamp.co.uk/css-slideshow/images/blanks/a.png" />
        <img src="http://www.codelamp.co.uk/css-slideshow/images/blanks/b.png" />
        <img src="http://www.codelamp.co.uk/css-slideshow/images/blanks/c.png" />
        <img src="http://www.codelamp.co.uk/css-slideshow/images/blanks/d.png" />
        <img src="http://www.codelamp.co.uk/css-slideshow/images/blanks/e.png" />
    </figure>
</div>
<style>
    @keyframes slidy {
    0% { left: 0%; }
    25% { left: -100%; }
    50% { left: -200%; }
    75% { left: -300%; }
    100% { left: -400%; }
    }
    body { margin: 0; } 
    div#slider { overflow: hidden; }
    div#slider figure img { width: 20%; float: left; }
    div#slider figure { 
    position: relative;
    width: 500%;
    margin: 0;
    left: 0;
    text-align: left;
    font-size: 0;
    animation: 30s slidy infinite; 
    }
    .css-slider-mask{
    width:300px;
    height:300px;
    }
</style>
```

how change position current image ?
I tried

```
document.querySelector('figure').getBoundingClientRect()
ClientRect {top: 0, right: 930.609375, bottom: 0, left: -569.390625, width: 1500…}
```

but when i change

```
document.querySelector('figure').style.position.left = '-110px'
```

no change in view ! Why ?

I want to change the position of the animation .Javascript has access to the  keyframe object ?

Comment: run This and Show all properties using Inspect Element and edit there then implement. it will work definitely. when you refresh page then refresh using " Ctrl + Shift + R " press all button simultaneously.

Answer (score 0):

Properties set in keyframe animations take precedence over everything else while they are active. Since the `figure` has an infinitely running animation that affects its `left` property, changing the property directly will have no visible effect.

What do you want to happen to the animation once you pick a specific `left` value?

- If you want to jump to the given position and stop there, simply disable the animation by also setting `animation: none;`
- If you want "pause" the animation at the given position and resume it later, you'll need to control the animation much more explicitly using Javascript. CSS animations always start from 0% (or 100% if running in reverse) when activated; they cannot "resume" from an arbitrary point in the middle after they have been disabled.